# Get map from map by vector of keys

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I was wondering, if there is a function of std::map to receive a sub-map defined by a std::vector of keys. So just like the `std::map.at(key)` function but with a std::vector of keys. I know I can iterate over the map and adding the map pairs to a new map, but I was wondering, if there is a built in function, or maybe a faster way to get a sub-map.

example code:

```
std::map<std::string, int> map = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 4}, {"e", 5}};
std::vector<std::string> keys = {"a", "c", "d"};
// using iteration:
std::map<std::string, int> new_map;
for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it){
    if(std::find(keys.begin(), keys.end(), it->first) != keys.end()){
        new_map.insert(*it);
    }
}
// new_map should be {{"a",1}, {"c",3}, {"d",4}}

// What I am hoping to find is something like:
new_map = map.at(keys);

//resulting in the same new_map {{"a",1}, {"c",3}, {"d",4}}.
```

Is there such a function or in general a smarter way than iterating over the whole map and using the find function every time (I know I could iterate over the vector, but this doesn't make much of a difference, or does it?).

Comment: Can you not just iterate over the keys, check if that key is present in `map` and if it is, copy the key-value pair from `map` to `new_map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I could iterate over the vector, but this doesn't make much of a difference, or does it?

It does make a difference, because iterating in order is typically faster for a vector than for a map (vectors data is local in memory, a maps elements are not) and finding an element is faster in a map than in a vector (`O(log(N))` vs `O(N)` for an unsorted vector).

Lets say you have `M` elements in the map and `N` keys in the vector, then your approach is `O( M * N)` while swapping iteration and finding would be only `O( N * log(M))`. This only takes into account the complexity for `find`. Taking into account the iteration is more involved as it very much depends on cache.

Otherwise, I think your approach is fine. I am not aware of an algorithm that would make your code more concise or expressive.

**PS** you might consider this as a nitpick on wording, but as it happens too often that one overthinks a problem I will mention it: "a smarter way" is not always "a better way". Dont try to be too smart. Most algorithms can be replaced by a simple loop, but often they are considered more expressive and readable than the handwritten loop. Trying to squeeze something into algorithms when there is no algorithm for the problem at hand, often results in less readable and less expressive code. If someone finds an algorithm that can be used here, I'll take back everything in this PS :P

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will leave the question open for a bit to see, if anybody else has something to add before accepting.

Comment: @LeoE sure, I wanted to write a comment first, but it was too long. Would be interesting to see if someone comes along with an algorithm, though I dont think one can beat `O(N * log(M))`

Comment: @LeoE Is your `keys` strictly a vector? Can you use another container for it? If you use `std::unordered_set`, its lookup is `O(1)`. Overall complexity then will be `O(M)`.

Comment: No, the keys are allowed to be something other than vector.

Comment: @LeoE Then, I would try `std::unordered_set<std::string> keys = {"a", "c", "d"};` and `if (keys.find(it->first) != keys.end()) ...`.

Comment: But it then really depends on the size of keys and map which one is faster, right? Assuming I have a lot less keys, than map entries @formerlyknownas_463035818 approach would be faster, right?

Comment: @LeoE Very likely. Take extreme cases. If you have just one key, then you will end up just with one lookup in a map. On the contrary, if you have many keys and just one entry in the map, the opposite approach will be faster. What will be faster generally very much depend on actual data.

Comment: @LeoE i took the example in your question as .. an example. For this size of input, I doubt you will see any difference. Note that complexity is about asymptotic behaviour and this is only meaningful for `M` **and** `N` being huge. If either of the two is considerably small the situation can be very different

Comment: @LeoE ...but then on the other hand, if either of the two is small, you shouldnt worry too much about performance in the first place ;)

Comment: Not necessarily small, just smaller, I was just thinking about checking for size first and then choosing the better approach. Thanks in any case, it answered my question very well, I'll see, if either make a large difference to the other

Answer (score 2):

I would also consider using `std::copy_if` algorithm. It does not save too many characters in the source code here, but it's more explicit:

```
std::map<std::string, int> map = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 4}, {"e", 5}};
std::unordered_set<std::string> keys = {"a", "c", "d"};
std::map<std::string, int> new_map;

std::copy_if(map.begin(), map.end(),
             std::inserter(new_map, new_map.end()),
             [&keys](const auto& e){ return keys.find(e.first) != keys.end(); });
```

Live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/imqrtHndVY1UOpD8).

---

In C++20, we will be able to write this even more compactly:

```
std::copy_if(map.begin(), map.end(),
             std::inserter(new_map, new_map.end()),
             [&keys](const auto& e){ return keys.contains(e.first); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from formerlyknownas_463035818's answer (so iterating over `keys` instead over `map`) seems to me that the "algorithm way" (meaning: using the standard algorithms in `<algorithm>` header) could be the use of `std::transform()`

```
std::transform(keys.cbegin(), keys.cend(),
               std::inserter(new_map, new_map.end()),
               [&](auto const & k) -> std::pair<std::string, int>
                { return {k, map[k]}; });
```

but (IMHO) is far more readable the good-old loop way

```
for ( auto const & k : keys )
   new_map[k] = map[k];
```

Off Topic Unrequested Suggestion: don't use "`map`" (the same name of the class, ignoring the namespace) for a "`std::map`" variable. Maybe works and nobody add a `using std;`... but why challenge fate?